# wordpress and the $_GET method

Tags: wordpress, get-method

I have recently updated a plain html website for a music festival into wordpress. All is fine and beautifulllllll(!), except for one thing. People who apply for the courses are supposed to pay for a deposit, and when they do so they should receive a confirmation email that includes a URL for the future payment of the rest of the course fee. 
With the old site, we used to have something like:

> http://www.mysite.com/coursefee.php?amount=10&refno=1234&name=John

The **coursefee.php** file used the $_GET method to create a form that would lead to the payment service (with the right amount to be paid, the correct reference number, ASO). The problem is that if I use the same configuration in wordpress.... well, things don't work. Wordpress uses url parameters as query parameters and I really don't know how to go around this issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Try get_query_var('refno') and print_r($wp_query)

Comment: Even if its not a query but just form data?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the path to your **coursefee.php** files is in the wordpress root directory ?

This php file is not part of Wordpress core, so if you have the standard `.htaccess` file, you should access it directly without initializing WordPress.

Comment: Well, I didn't just copy the coursefee.php file into my directory. I have created a page template with more or less the same code (which is just a form that gets the data using the GET method). And that's where I'm stuck :-/

Comment: Can you modify in some ways the parameter's names with prefixes for instances ? `cf-amount`, `cf-refno`, `cf-name`...

Comment: Would that make a difference? I must try! Anyway, I found a solution in this website [link](http://www.webopius.com/content/137/using-custom-url-parameters-in-wordpress). For now, it's doing what I wanted. I just hope this doesn't create any security issues :P